# Change sender of e-mail reply depending on recipient of original mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

Is it possible to achieve the following using Outlook as the e-mail client: If I create a reply, its *sender* address should match the *recipient* of the mail I am replying to.

For example, I may receive mails directed either at me, personally (*me@company.com*), or at my department's distribution group (*department@company.com*). My goal is to be able to hit "Reply", type my response and send it, with the following condition: If the original mail was sent to *me@company.com*, then the sender of the reply should also be *me@company.com*. If the recipient was *department@company.com*, then the reply should be sent by *department@company.com*. In actuality, Outlook will in both cases use *me@company.com* as the sender.

Is this at all possible, and if so, how do I go about it? Maybe using a macro?

Comment: See [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/92444/outlook-reply-as-email-address-the-message-was-sent-to)

Comment: which version of outlook is this? arent the 2 recipients from 2 seperate "accounts"?

Comment: @Raystafarian You're right, the question is the same as mine. However, none of the answers actually solve the problem: I want the sender of the reply to be the same as the recipient of the original mail - I don't want to send as the same sender in both cases.

Comment: @Psycogeek It is Outlook 2003. There is only one actual account, the other address is that of a distribution group.

Comment: Yeah, I pointed you to the thread because the only way I know how to do this is by showing the `from` field and changing it. I'm not sure it's possible, unless you want to edit the registry key so there's no `from` in which case it'd start to get annoying